# MediaTemple cron jobs working on 1&1 Internet?

Tags: hosting, installation, cron, mailing-list, mediatemple

I've having to get a cron job that's currently working on MediaTemple (Grid Service) to work on a new 1&1 Internet account. I've yet to do this yet, but is there anything I need to take into consideration? Or... effectively... cron jobs are cron jobs, they'll work where ever?

It's a cron job to send out a mailing list from a database.

Anything I need to consider to make it work smoothly?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about php, you may check first max_execution_time in php, in case the process of sending the list gets over that time, wich may not be very good.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to explore 1&1's mailing limits. (They may prefer you send to no more than N email addresses.)

I *think* with 1&1 you can set custom values like max_execution_time via .htaccess. You may also want to monitor how much memory this uses and set the appropriate php_flag.

Best of luck!